# How to Loop a Controller to Ajax and then bind it with View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

The code below calls the database tables but I want the values displayed below the search button as I have it in my database List

**My Controller**

```
 public JsonResult GetTerm(string searchText)
        {
            IEnumerable<FileDetails> fileDetails = new List<FileDetails>();
            var files = (from a in _context.FileDetails
                         where a.FileName.Contains(searchText)
                         select new
                         {
                             a.Imagename,
                             a.FileName,
                             a.CategoriesName
                         }).ToList();
            return Json(files, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**My View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Knowledge.Model.Models.FileDetails>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Dashboard", "FileManagement", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
                <input type="text" id="searchId" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" onInput="edValueKeyPress()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
}
```

**My Ajax**

```
function edValueKeyPress() {
    var eValue = document.getElementById("searchId");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/FileManagement/GetTerm',
        data: { searchText: eValue.value },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {

        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

So my query is to view the values which pass through the `Controller` section in the UI page. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Without 3rd party components. Write your on success function that will generate table from received data. Then replace certain div with this table.
2. Use 3rd party components that will do this work for you. If you use bootstrap I personally recommend https://bootstrap-table.com/ or https://datatables.net/ Both components have very good documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. But can you give me an example of how I can implement with the first option?. Thanks in advance!